# How to properly throw an Exception inside yield return method in C#

Tags: c#, exception, yield-return

See edits below for reproducing the behavior that I describe in this problem.

The following program will never end, because the `yield return` construct in C# calls the `GetStrings()` method indefinitely when an exception is thrown.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // I expect the Exception to be thrown here, but it's not
        foreach (var str in GetStrings())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(str);
        }
    }

    private static IEnumerable<string> GetStrings()
    {
        // REPEATEDLY throws this exception
        throw new Exception();
        yield break;
    }
}
```

For this trivial example, I could obviously use `return Enumerable.Empty<string>();` instead, and the problem goes away.  However in a more interesting example, I'd expect the exception to be thrown once, then have the method stop being called and throw the exception in the method that's "consuming" the `IEnumerable`.

Is there a way to produce this behavior?

EDIT: ok, the problem is different than I first thought.  The program above does NOT end, and the `foreach` loop behaves like an infinite loop.  The program below DOES end, and the exception is displayed on the console.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (var str in GetStrings())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(str);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }
    }

    private static IEnumerable<string> GetStrings()
    {
        throw new Exception();
        yield break;
    }
}
```

Why does the `try` ... `catch` block make a difference in this case?  This seems very strange to me.  Thanks to @AndrewKilburn for his answer already for pointing me to this.

EDIT #2:
From a Command Prompt, the program executes the same in both cases.  In Visual Studio Enterprise 2015, Update 2, whether I compile in Debug or Release, the behavior above is what I am seeing.  With the `try` ... `catch`, the program ends with an exception, and without it Visual Studio never closes the program.

EDIT #3: Fixed
For me, the issue was resolved by the answer by @MartinBrown.  When I uncheck Visual Studio's option under Debug > Options > Debugging > General > "Unwind the call stack on unhandled exceptions" this problem goes away.  When I check the box again, then the problem comes back.

Comment: I tried it and it throws only once. In the case of wrapping `foreach` with `try catch` exception has been catched also only once and program quits. Did I understand it correctly?

Comment: Hmmm, I'm not seeing that behavior.  Let me check again to be sure.  The behavior I am seeing is that the exception is thrown, and it is caught somehow behind the scenes and the `foreach` loop is behaving like an infinite loop.

Comment: @Szer See my edit, the `try` ... `catch` blocks seem to make a difference in whether the foreach loop acts as an infinite loop.  Does that make any sense to you?

Comment: I cannot reproduce "infinite loop" behavior. Without `try catch` program crashed as soon as exception has been thrown.

Comment: Are you debugging this in Visual Studio? Which version are you using? I've seen odd occasions where Visual Studio fails to move on after showing an exception making it appear that the exception is thrown more than once when it isn't. Not sure the exact circumstances that cause it though.

Comment: @Szer If you put a break point in and follow it, once it hits the exception it wont stop throwing it, it doesnt loop round. It just keeps throwing it. Mark my answer as the chosen answer if correct please

Comment: @MartinBrown I'm using Visual Studio Enterprise 2015, compiling with Debug "Any CPU".  When I click on Help > About Microsoft Visual Studio, I see the version is "Version 14.0.25123.00 Update 2"

Comment: Im using VS2015 Pro Update 2 with Debug AnyCPU on x64 Win7. Try [this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/EppiDs) fiddle. Uncomment trycatch and you will see thats everything is fine

Comment: @Szer I could post a video or something, but my program really isn't ending without the try ... catch.  I'm on x64 Windows 10

Comment: @JohnCarpenter Have you tried running it outside Visual Studio?

Comment: @Szer also note that the `yield break;` is important.  Your fiddle doesn't have that in the `GetStrings()` method.  Without `yield break;` the method executes as I would expect.

Comment: @MartinBrown yes, it behaves as I would expect outside of Visual Studio.  Now that it seems to be a Visual Studio problem, is there a better place than SO for the question?

Comment: I have the exact same version as you, exact same OS as well.  Crashes like a ton of bricks on any jitter and any framework target and any of the available debugging engines.  You'll need to get your machine fixed.

Comment: Based on your last comment it seems the behavior you are seeing is caused by Visual Studio's debugger which swallows the unhandled exception (version w/o try/catch)? Am I interpreting that (edit #2) correctly? I am not even sure there is such a setting in VS that would do this but maybe it would then help to post a screenshot of your VS debug settings.

Comment: n/m, I see that you have accepted an answer with what I was thinking.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The behaviour being seen here is not a fault in the code; rather it is a side effect of the Visual Studio debugger. This can be resolved by turning off stack unwinding in Visual Studio. Try going into Visual Studio options Debugging/General and unchecking "Unwind the call stack on unhandled exceptions". Then run the code again.

What happens is that when your code hits a completely unhandled exception Visual Studio is unwinding the call stack to just before the line in your code that caused the exception. It does this so that you can edit the code and continue execution with the edited code.

The issue seen here looks like an infinite loop because when you re-start execution in the debugger the next line to run is the one that just caused an exception. Outside the debugger the call stack would be completely unwound on an unhandled exception and thus would not cause the same loop that you get in the debugger.

This stack unwinding feature can be turned off in the settings, it is enabled by default. Turning it off however will stop you being able to edit code and continue without first unwinding the stack yourself. This however is quite easy to do either from the call stack window or by simply selecting 'Enable Editing' from the Exception Assistant.

Comment: This fixed the issue.  Any explanation as to why?

Comment: Sadly my knoledge of what that actually does is a bit limited. Let me know if ever you figure it out.

Comment: @JohnCarpenter [Here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/saraford/2008/08/08/did-you-know-what-unwinding-the-call-stack-on-unhandled-exceptions-does-277/) is described the functionality. (You can find description in comments)

Comment: @MatteoUmili I've filled out the answer a bit following some reading on the subject.

Comment: Did this go away for VS 2017? @MartinBrown

Comment: @mike I've not had the opportunity to use 2017 yet, so couldn't comment.

Comment: @Mike It appears, yes it has gone away in VS2017.  :( See Hans Passant's comment on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43126140/continue-after-an-unhandled-exception-in-visual-studio-2017

Answer (score 1):

> The following program will never end

That's false.  The program is going to end quite quickly.

> because the yield return construct in C# calls the `GetStrings()` method indefinitely when an exception is thrown.

This is false.  It doesn't do this at all.

> I'd expect the exception to be thrown once, then have the method stop being called and throw the exception in the method that's "consuming" the `IEnumerable`.

That's exactly what *does* happen.

> Is there a way to produce this behavior?

Use the code you already provided.

Comment: Well it turned out not to be. Apparently the behavior was different within Visual Studio. Or at least appeared different. :)

Comment: Extremely unhelpful

Answer (score 0):

```
  class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            try {
                foreach (var item in GetStrings()) {
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {

        }
    }
    private static IEnumerable<string> GetStrings() {
        // REPEATEDLY throws this exception
        throw new Exception();
        yield break;
    }
}
```

Putting it in a try catch causes it to break out and do whatever you want

Comment: Unfortunately, that won't work because the exception isn't being thrown at all in the `Main` method.

Comment: This is interesting... putting the try catch makes the program behave differently.  Without the `try` ... `catch` does the program ever end for you?

Comment: @JohnCarpenter Mines the same, it doesn't end. The exception keeps getting thrown but it does not go around the foreach

Answer (score 0):

```
class Program
{
    public static int EnumerableCount;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        EnumerableCount = 0;
        try
        {
            foreach (var str in GetStrings())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(str);
                Console.Read();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            Console.Read();
        }
    }

    private static IEnumerable<string> GetStrings()
    {
        EnumerableCount++;
        var errorMessage = string.Format("EnumerableCount: {0}", EnumerableCount);
        throw new Exception(errorMessage);
        yield break;
    }
}
```

has the following output:

```
System.Exception: EnumerableCount: 1
  at {insert stack trace here}
```

The execution flow goes into the GetStrings() method the for the first iteration, the exception is thrown and caught in the Main() method. After hitting enter, the program exits.

Removing the try catch in the Main() method causes the exception to go unhandled. The output is then:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.Exception: EnumerableCount: 1
  at {insert stack trace here}
```

and the program crashes.