# Enable editing after an unhandled exception in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

How can I continue execution after an unhandled exception in Visual Studio 2017?

In version 2015 and below this was easily done by clicking `Enable Editing` which "unwinds the callstack to the point before the exception". It was then possible to edit the execution point, variables and code.

---

This option is gone when a library throws the exception:

[image]

```
"".Substring(1);
```

---

In case the exception happens in user code it still works:

[image]

```
int x = 0;
Console.WriteLine(1 / x);
```

Notice the yellow arrow which can be dragged.

---

I really hope this feature was not removed because salvaging a crashing program (here, by setting `x = 1` for example, changing the string constant or by skipping the problematic line) is something I do a lot. Right now I have a multi-hour operation 99% completed in this state and I'd really like to rescue it by suppressing an unimportant error.

This is Visual Studio 2017 build 26228 on .NET 4.6.1.

Comment: Tools > Options > Debugging > General > "Unwind the call stack on unhandled exception" checkbox.  Yes, it is gone in VS2017, a very inconvenient truth.  This was overdue work, the debugger in VS2015 (especially the Exception Assistant) were getting far too buggy.  The only real way to get it back is to [let them know about you not being happy](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide).

Comment: User voice issue: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/18797173-unwind-the-call-stack-on-unhandled-exception

Comment: The option to "Enable Editing" on the new exception window is gone, but it seems you can enable editing as soon as you attempt to type. I would rather have the feature be explicit though, automatic things are harder to troubleshoot. 

I'm able to just edit without clicking anything after an unhandled exception in vs2017 15.3.2. There is some slight lag after the first keystroke, but after I place my cursor somewhere in the file and type, the padlock disappears indicating the file isn't edit locked and I'm typing in the file like normal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In VS2017 the old "Enable Editing" is hidden and triggered automatically. While debugging, I'm able to edit the code / variables after unhandled exception if I do the following:

1. Click in the document to take focus off the new Exception Helper
2. Hit spacebar (or your whichever key is your favorite!)

OR

1. Drag the yellow arrow (green arrow for library).

Before hitting a key or moving the arrow there is the padlock on the file tab telling you it's edit-locked. After, the lock is removed just like the old "Enable Editing" feature. That first keystroke that removes the edit-lock isn't entered into the file, after that, editing code and variables behaves just as before.

I preferred the explicit "Enable Editing" link as it was before, hopefully they bring it back.

Answer (score 0):

Having run into this issue time and again, since I switched to 2017, I finally found this question, and found out that it actually works for exception from "My Code". Thanks for educating me on that!

But I was also wondering if it doesn't perhaps works on the "green arrow", and it actually works now! I'm running 15.2, so if it doesn't work for you yet, perhaps try upgrading to the latest version.

Comment: Does it also work when a library throws? I can't move the green arrow then.

Comment: That's weird, I'm quite certain I had it working on the green arrow, as well. Though, I cannot reproduce it anymore. I don't remember the exact conditions I was trying it (which repo, what kind of exception, either async, or not), so might be that it's working under limited circumstances. I keep an eye out for it, and if I can reproduce it, I'll update my answer. Sorry for the "false positive".

Answer (score -3):

You can have the application not send exceptions to the debugger:

`Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode(UnhandledExceptionMode.ThrowException);`

Works for me in VS 2017.

Comment: This is new to me. I was hoping for a solution for exceptions after the fact. Thanks for your contribution, though. This might help someone else.

Comment: @Fabi In case you're wondering, I've downvoted you, since it's not answering the OPs question, IMHO.